# Fill the terminal screen with dots

Tags: bash, terminal

I'd like to create a function `draw` which fills the terminal with dots.

According to http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html:

> Move the cursor forward N columns: \033[< N>C

In the first place, I did this to fill the first column:

```
draw_col() {
    local cols=$(tput cols)

    local x=0

    while [[ ${x} -lt ${cols} ]]
    do
        echo -en "\033[${x}C."
        x=$(( x+1 ))
    done

}
```

[image: draw_cols.png]

Why didn't only the first column get fully filled?

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because printing the dot moves the cursor one position right, too. "Moving forward" means from the current position, not from the line beginning.

Comment: Well I do need another coffee :D, thank you